# How to get data type of a column?

Tags: c#, odbc, datareader, idatareader

I use Northwind sample database and ODBC. For my C# application I want to get the data type of a column as Type object (not as String), because I want to use the Type for some reasons.

Example (taken from Northwind) - Table OrderDetails contains columns:

`OrderID type int(11), ProductID type int(11), UnitPrice type float, etc.`

I want to get something like:

```
Type dataType = (the data type of OrderID)
```

**NOT:** `string dataType = reader.GetString(dataTypeOrdinal); // I can get this without any problem.`

Here is code fragment:  (I put also some detailed comments in the code)

```
var connectionString = Database.ConnectionString;
var command = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = \'" + _name + "\'";
IDataReader reader = null;
reader = _database.Provider.ExecuteReader(command, false);
while (reader.Read())
{
    var columnNameOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("column_name");
    var dataTypeOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("data_type");
    var columnName = reader.GetString(columnNameOrdinal);
    // till line above everything works fine
    // ---------my problem starts below ---------------
    // I don't need data type as string like this:
    // var dataTypeName = reader.GetString(dataTypeOrdinal);
    // but rather something like: Type dataType = (the data type of column)
    // I tried using reader.GetData(dataTypeOrdinal), but I get
    // System.NotSupportedException: "Specified method is not supported."
}
```

Any help and hints are highly appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
var type = reader.GetFieldType(columnNameOrdinal);
```

or if you want provider specific type you can use

```
var providerSpecificType=    reader.GetProviderSpecificFieldType(int ordinal);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetProviderSpecificFieldType);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

```
Gets an Object that is a representation of the underlying provider-specific field type.
```

Comment: I tried GetProviderSpecificFieldType but get error: 'System.Data.IDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'GetProviderSpecificFieldType' and no extension method 'GetProviderSpecificFieldType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.IDataReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what type of provider you are using ??

Comment: as far as I can see it is Sql Provider. Which would you suggest so that GetProviderSpecificFieldType works?

Comment: if it's SQLServer it should work as it is fully  microsoft supported